# Active Admin + cancan. How can I remove header link keeping cancan ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, activeadmin, cancan

I'm using **ActiveAdmin** with **CanCan gem** and I have the next situation:

- Two roles:  **admin**, **other**.
- The admin's header with three links: **link1 | link2 | link3**
- Link 3 represents a **Video** resource.
- The **admin user** can see links 1, 2 and 3
- The **other user** can see link 1 and 2 but **NOT** 3

So, to make **link 3** disappear. I can have an **abilities.rb file** with:

```
can :manage, Video #for admin users
```

and nothing for **other** users. This will make **link 3** disappear.
But, in other sections of my app I want **other** users with ability to "read Videos". When I add this ability, the link appears into the header again.

The question is: How can I **preserve** my :

```
can :read, Video #for other users
```

and disappear **link 3** at the same time?

Comment: Why would you want the menu link to be missing if the user has permissions to view that resource?

Comment: It's a client requirement. The "other" user can analyze videos from app side but clients don't want those users seeing videos from admin side (yes, "other user" can access other things on admin side). I just don't want active admin adding links automatically based on defined abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Video do
  menu :if => proc { !current_user.other? }

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I think that this solution still gives access to the menu functionalities through direct typing of the URL. Does anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to override the default menu visibility for those people who have CanCan access but shouldn't see the menu item:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Video do
  menu false if current_user.other?

  # ...
end
```

Comment: current_user it's not defined on that level. +1 for the clue